# Apache reverse proxy for Kibana

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, reverse-proxy

I'm currently trying to set up an Apache server to redirect e.g localhost/kibana to Kibana at localhost:5601.

I've tried adding this to apache2.conf:

```
ProxyPass /kibana http://localhost:5601
ProxyPassReverse /kibana http://localhost:5601
```

However it gets stuck on the Kibana "loading components" page and never actually loads fully. It works when changed to this:

```
ProxyPass /kibana/ http://localhost:5601/
ProxyPassReverse /kibana/ http://localhost:5601/
```

Obviously it's not ideal to force the user to enter the extra / at the end though, so I've tried rewriting the URL in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://localhost/kibana$ http://localhost/kibana/
```

But the rewrite doesn't seem to work. I've set AllowOverride to all and enabled the rewrite module, as well as played around with various different rewrite/proxy rules but haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have finished my apache configuration file for kibana with elasticsearch. It may be useful for you:

/etc/httpd/conf.d/kibana.conf:

```
ProxyRequests On

ProxyPass /app/kibana http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana
ProxyPassReverse /app/kibana http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana

ProxyPass /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200/
ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200/

Alias /bundles/ /opt/kibana/optimize/bundles/

<Directory /opt/kibana>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This way it does not require any additional "/" and it works with default kibana configuration file.